# Gremlin Group by two properties

Tags: gremlin, titan

I have a Titan graph database with Merchants and their sales information.a Merchant have a set of sales vertices's connected by an edge with a property named "Year","Month","Date".

Is it possible to write a Gremlin (or anything else Titan would support) query to: get sales amount group by year and month.(Without date). 
**I want get result set like this:**

```
YEAR MONTH AMOUNT
2014  01    250$
2014  02    123$
2014  03    124$
```

is it possible to group by using two parameters ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to do:

```
g.V.has('type','sales').groupBy{"${it.year}/${it.month}"}{it.amount}{it.sum()}
```

Basically that code groups on the concatenation of year and month properties.  If you needed the individual month/year you could parse it back out.